# Can't get past the grub on install

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I don't have the faintest clue as to what's going on. I boot from USB and click to install or boot, and it gives me the following screen. Does anyone know what's going on or what I can do to fix this? I have the Asus g75vw. i7, 8gb ram, nvidia gtx 660 mobile. I know there are issues with install normally, but these are different from what i'm experiencing.

[image]